# Difference between apple developer and enterprise account

Tags: ios, enterprise

I have two credential for the apple developer account.

I want to differentiation between apple developer account and enterprise account.
Is it mention anywhere in itunes account and apple devloper account that it is enterprise and this is developer account.
Please help.
I am new in this.

Comment: Do you have a regular developer account and an enterprise developer account but are unable to tell the difference between them? Please clarify what your problem is.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have two apple developer (regular) account.

Comment: @molbdnilo but my client informed me that one is enterprise account(299$ enrollment) and another is apple developer (regular :- 99$).But how can i prove him that account is apple devloper regular one and not enterpirse one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the following link:   http://leolearning.com/blog/apple-developer-vs-apple-enterprise-licenses/   describes the Apple developer vs Apple enterprise licenses – what does it mean to you. 
[image]

Kind regards

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But if i had two account and i logged in into both the account with different system.how can i differential and which one is enterprise. Is anywhere( in appledeveloper account or in itunes) this is mention like while creating certificate or provisioning profile or anything?

Comment: You can go to your account settings and find your account information. (The Enterprise package should be used by prófessional app development)

Comment: @DeveloperOmari: Both accounts should be used by professionals. An Enterprise account can be use by a company for developing apps _distributed within that company_. On one hand you are not required to go through the app store and through Apple's reviews, on the other you are absolutely one hundred percent not allowed to make those apps available to anyone outside the enterprise.

Comment: Under which circumstances would a company develop only internal Apps? Wouldn't it be much more interesting for an Enterprise account to have the option to provide both, public AND internal apps? Or is the idea that each company gets two subscriptions, if they need both?

Comment: Take a look at this Link from Apple "Choosing a Membership"
https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Are how would i enrolled the enterprise account after i buy the apple developer account

Comment: so in enterprise account does not have any review to submit to appstore